# update with entityManager.merge in Java EE 6 application

Tags: merge, java-ee-6, entitymanager, insert-update

I used entityManager.merge(obj) to update in my application. But instead of updating the object, it inserts a new record. Please help me with this problem.

Here is my servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "PutAuthor", urlPatterns = {"/PutAuthor"})
public class PutAuthor extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private AuthorEntityFacade authorEntityFacade;
    @Resource(mappedName="jms/UpdateAuthorFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    @Resource(mappedName="jms/UpdateAuthor")
    private Queue queue;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        String description=request.getParameter("description");
        if ((name!=null) && (description!=null)) {
            try {
                Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
                ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();
                // here we create NewsEntity, that will be sent in JMS message
                AuthorEntity e = new AuthorEntity();
                e.setAuthorName(name);
                e.setDescription(description);
                message.setObject(e);
                messageProducer.send(message);
                messageProducer.close();
                connection.close();
                response.sendRedirect("ListAuthors");
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            /*
             * TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code.
             */
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Update Author</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Update Author</h1>");
            AuthorEntity author=(AuthorEntity)authorEntityFacade.find(Long.parseLong(id));
            out.println("<form>");
            out.println("Author ID      : <input type='number' name='id' value='"+id+"' readonly><br/>");
            out.println("Author Name    : <input type='text' name='name' value='"+author.getAuthorName()+"'><br/>");
            out.println("Description    : <textarea name='description'>"+author.getDescription()+"</textarea><br/>");
            out.println("<input type='submit'><br/>");
            out.println("</form>"); 
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Here is my message-driven bean:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/UpdateAuthor", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class UpdateAuthor implements MessageListener {
    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext mdc;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "IT11032748_Book_Catalogue-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public UpdateAuthor() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        ObjectMessage objectMessage=null;
        try{
            if(message instanceof ObjectMessage){
                objectMessage=(ObjectMessage)message;
                AuthorEntity author=(AuthorEntity)objectMessage.getObject();
                update(author);
            }
        }catch(JMSException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            mdc.setRollbackOnly();
        }catch(Throwable te){
            te.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void update(Object object) {
        em.merge(object);
    }
}
```

Please check where it has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. Merge will create the object if it's new or update the object if it's not. If you want more help you'll need to add more detail to your question.